# Some questions on Langlands Classification of Irreducible Admissible Representation

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to construct some representations using Langlands classification theorem. But I get confused and have some problems when constructing these representations.....

i) In the classification theorem, the Langlands parameter is  $(P,\sigma,\mu)$. Here P is a standard parabolic subgroup with Langlands decomposition $P=NAM$ and $\mu$ is a complex linear function on $\mathfrak{a}=Lie(A)$ such that $Re\mu$ lives in the open positive Weyl Chamber.

We know the classification of irreducible admissible representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. In particular, the limits of discrete series is irreducible and admissible, but in this case, $\mu=0$...... But in the classification theorem, we need $Re\mu>0$. Where do I misunderstand?

ii) I am also trying to construct irreducible admissible representations of $Sp_4(\mathbb{R})$, I know there are two standard parabolic subgroups. The corresponding Levi subgrous are $GL_2(\mathbb{R})\times GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $GL_1(\mathbb{R})\times{SL_2(\mathbb{R})}\times GL_1(\mathbb{R})$. Of course in the fisrt case, the first $GL_2(\mathbb{R)}$ determines the second, same thing happens to the two $GL_1(\mathbb{R})$ in the second case. Now I have some questions form here:

Question 1: In the second example, we need irreducible tempered representation of  $GL_1(\mathbb{R})\times{SL_2(\mathbb{R})}$, does it come from irreducible representation of $GL_1(\mathbb{R})$ tensor irreducible representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$? In general, for a  irreducible representation of $G\times H$, is it always the outer tensor product of two irrducble representations? I know this is true for compact Lie groups and reductive algebraic groups, but how about noncompact Lie groups? Also, does temper representation tensor representation always temper?

Question 2:  In the first example, we need to use the irreducible tempered representation of $M$. If we identify the Levi subgroup with the first $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, then we need irreducible tempered representation of the following group:
           $\big\{g\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})\lvert det(g)=\pm 1\big\}$

I kind of understand this must be related to irreducible admissible representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, but how should I deal with this disconnected group?

Thank you!